# Element type \"field\" must be followed by either attribute specifications, \">\" or \"/>\"."

Tags: field, ibm-cloud, retrieve-and-rank, solrconfig

I am try to make a collection with my solr
_config. I get the following error:

> {
>     "failure": {
>       "10.47.24.19:5285_solr": "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at https://10.47.24.19:5285/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'localWebCollection_shard1_replica2': Unable to create core [localWebCollection_shard1_replica2] Caused by: Element type \"field\" must be followed by either attribute specifications, \">\" or \"/>\".",
>       "10.44.121.52:6560_solr": "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at https://10.44.121.52:6560/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'localWebCollection_shard1_replica1': Unable to create core [localWebCollection_shard1_replica1] Caused by: Element type \"field\" must be followed by either attribute specifications, \">\" or \"/>\"."
>     }

I checked all the fields existing in my schema.xml. They are all closed with "/>". Any Ideas on how to fix this error?
Any helps or ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the 'space' between two of the attributes in one of the fields was removed! Seeing this error you should make sure that in the schema.xml all the attributes of each one of the fields are properly separated and that you have quoted the values of any of the attributes like "body", "false", "true"...etc. properly.